# Android fragments orientation change issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

Am using fragments in tabhost on bottom of screen with five tabs as contained in five fragments. Take as Fragment A,B,C,D,E.
All fragments am designed for portrait mode. When am in Fragment C then i rotate screen to landscape my screen goes to Fragment A not restoring in Fragment C.I have to stay in Fragment C when i rotate to landscape mode or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line in `Manifest.xml` with Activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```